# Why did Spud sign off the EU money to Veronica?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, t2-trainspotting

Towards the end of *T2: Trainspotting*, we are informed that the huge grant (100k) had been stolen by Veronica, as she made Spud forge Simon and Mark's signature. Spud got his share (which he deferred to his estranged family).

My question is, why would Spud do that? I mean, Mark saved his life (on top of never ripping him off in the first place). We aren't informed of any problems between Simon and Spud.

Spud would have gotten a share anyway...
And he knows it's a bad thing... He later tells that to his "friends" (He later saves their lives, which I guess evens the score).

Comment: Only reason I can see is that Veronica cared for him, she was interested in his stories, which neither Simon nor Mark did.